# Is this line of code jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm checking some code and found this row:

```
section0.top = $("#section0").position().top;
```

What is `section0.top` - is it a variable? I didn't see anywhere in jQuery documentation that I could put .top after the variable. I don't understand this syntax.

This is the whole function:

```
function calculateSections() {
    windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    section0.top = $("#section0").position().top;
}
```

Comment: Whatever it is, it isn't the most well-written code.

Comment: but it is code from a working site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML5 global variables are created [automatically](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-input) for each element that has an `id` attribute, and those variable names *are* the `id` values.

So without any explicit declaration your document will have the `section0` variable, and its value is the corresponding `HtmlElement` object. The assignment you refer to will thus add a `top` property to that object.

NB: this is behaviour that is unrelated to jQuery

NB2: it is not considered best practice to add properties to DOM objects.

Comment: This is a great explanation, didn't know about this thing; thank you for it

Answer (score 0):

According to this function documentation:

https://api.jquery.com/position/

`Returns an object containing the properties top and left.`

It means that position() over a selector is a jQuery function but at the end its just returning a javascript object in this format:

```
{top: 0, left: 0}
```

It menas that you can add a chainable access to the property, in this case `top`

Note that position() is not a jQuery variable but a method.